# Error when apply custom patch using command

Tags: magento2, patches, magento2.4.3

I have to remove some logic of magento core file so I have created the custom patch file orderfilter.patch using the below command.

```
diff -u vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/CollectionModified.php > orderfilter.patch

    diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php b/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
    --- vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
    +++ vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
    @@ -69,13 +69,13 @@
      */
     public function addFieldToFilter($field, $condition = null)
     {
-        if ($field === 'created_at') {
-            if (is_array($condition)) {
-                foreach ($condition as $key => $value) {
-                    $condition[$key] = $this->timeZone->convertConfigTimeToUtc($value);
-                }
-            }
-        }
+        // if ($field === 'created_at') {
+        //     if (is_array($condition)) {
+        //         foreach ($condition as $key => $value) {
+        //             $condition[$key] = $this->timeZone->convertConfigTimeToUtc($value);
+        //         }
+        //     }
+        // }
 
         return parent::addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
     }
```

I have placed this generated patch file in m2hotfix in the root of Magento and running using below command

```
patch < orderfilter.patch
```

But getting error as below

```
patch < orderfilter.patch
can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you should have used the -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php b/vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
|--- vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
|+++ vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
--------------------------
File to patch: ../vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php
../vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php: **Invalid cross-device link**
Skip this patch? [y] y
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Comment: tried ``patch < orderfilter.patch -p`` ?

Comment: it gives patch: option requires an argument -- 'p'
patch: Try 'patch --help' for more information.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
diff -u vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php app/code/vendor/module/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/CollectionModified.php > ../orderfilter.patch
```

Comment: I have also used this it's generating same file. Issue is Invalid cross-device link. Do you know about this?